# WSASend send order across multiple sockets

Tags: windows, sockets, network-programming, winsock2

If I have **one** socket, and I do overlapped `WSASend`s (from a single thread), then windows guarantees data will be sent in the order I call `WSASend`.

But if I have **two** sockets (connected to the same receiver), and I do overlapped `WSASend`'s on them alternately (again from a single thread), does windows guarantee the order of sends is the order in which I call `WSASend`? If the answer is no, then would it help if I set the `SO_SNDBUF` socket option to zero on both sockets (so that calling `WSASend` would immediately put it on the wire)?

I also have the same question for `WSARecv`. If from a single thread I do overlapped `WSARecv`'s on multiple sockets, will the completion routines be called in order?

Comment: Why? Even if here was such a guaranteed it wouldn't extend to the ordering at the receiver. The network could reorder the packets any way it likes.

Comment: If order of operations is important to you, you have to explicitly synchronize your reads/writes accordingly. Don't expect Windows to do it for you.